# Reference constants in type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, constants

Typescript weirdness:

```
export type MyType = 0 | 1 | 2;
```

This works. But this does not:

```
export const ONE = 1;
export const TWO = 2;
export const THREE = 3;
export type MyType = ONE | TWO | THREE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the second example you are in typespace using a value (the declared consts) to declare a type. you need to use typeof ONE TWO or THREE. In the first example, 1 2 and 3 count as types themselves.

Comment: typeof ONE is a number, but it can be any number, so it would not be the same

Comment: no typeof ONE is 1. it would be the exact same if before each one of them typeof is added. It only would not if you added `:number ` to your const variables

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining `MyType` as a type and there you're referencing a variable. So what you need to actually do to match types with types is to request the type of your value. You can do that by using the `typeof` operator like:

```
export const ONE = 1;
export const TWO = 2;
export const THREE = 3;
export type MyType = typeof ONE | typeof TWO | typeof THREE;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wPIDkCicC8cAjANwCwAUKJLIiunACoDqGBcATOVeNPEmniMAEgCUceQgGZu1PnBgBPMMDgBZRY2WrCSlRABmcbHgA%20C7Yaas45vcCsjxObpSA)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use typeof, like mentioned in previous answer.

Second, if I understand correctly, you want to create type containing excatly these 3 given values. To do this, you need to use `as const` keywords.

For example:

```
export const A = 1 as const;
export const B = 2 as const;
export type MyType = typeof A | typeof B;
```

and more usefull example for const variable:

```
export const status = {
  FIRST: 1,
  SECOND: 2
} as const;

export type StatusType = typeof status[keyof typeof status];

export interface IEntity {
  id: number;
  status: StatusType;
}

// You can use it elsewhere like this:
const A: IEntity = {
  id: 1,
  type: status.FIRST
};
```